# Is there a way to add just google-play-services.jar to make map v2 work?

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-android-api-2

I wanna add just `google-play-services.jar` to my project and make map v2 work without adding  google-play-services_lib as a library to my project, is that possible ?

i try to do that lot of times and ways, but every one make an exception, expel :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:279)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:558)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no because it needs additional resources such as images and styles as you can see by the error that are not in just the jar file